# h5py File Method Override

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

I'm trying to create a child class of a h5py file that will be useful in my scripting and in interactive mode, so I want my class to have the option to provide a file name or call for a pop-up file selection GUI.  I believe I need to override the h5py.File.**init**() with my own options, but not working as expected...

For example, this works...

```
import h5py
x = h5py.File('myfile.h5')
>>> x
<HDF5 file "myfile.h5" (mode r+)>
```

But this does not...

```
import h5py

class MyH5(h5py.File):

    def __init__(self, filename='', initialdir=None, gui=False):
        if gui == False:
            self = h5py.File(filename, 'r')
        elif gui == True:
            opts = {}
            opts['filetypes'] = [('HDF-Time History Files','.H5'),('all files','.*')]
            opts['title'] = 'Choose an HDF file...'
            opts['initialdir'] = initialdir
            filename = askopenfilename(**opts)  # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file
            self = h5py.File(filename, 'r')

x = MyH5('myfile.h5')

>>> x
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    670                 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
    671                 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
--> 672             printer.pretty(obj)
    673             printer.flush()
    674             return stream.getvalue()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\pretty.py in pretty(self, obj)
    381                             if callable(meth):
    382                                 return meth(obj, self, cycle)
--> 383             return _default_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
    384         finally:
    385             self.end_group()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\pretty.py in _default_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
    501     if _safe_getattr(klass, '__repr__', None) not in _baseclass_reprs:
    502         # A user-provided repr. Find newlines and replace them with p.break_()
--> 503         _repr_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
    504         return
    505     p.begin_group(1, '<')

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\pretty.py in _repr_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
    699     """A pprint that just redirects to the normal repr function."""
    700     # Find newlines and replace them with p.break_()
--> 701     output = repr(obj)
    702     for idx,output_line in enumerate(output.splitlines()):
    703         if idx:

h5py\_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (C:\Minonda\conda-bld\h5py_1482647201869\work\h5py\_objects.c:2866)()

h5py\_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (C:\Minonda\conda-bld\h5py_1482647201869\work\h5py\_objects.c:2824)()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py in __repr__(self)
    320     @with_phil
    321     def __repr__(self):
--> 322         if not self.id:
    323             r = six.u('<Closed HDF5 file>')
    324         else:

h5py\_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (C:\Minonda\conda-bld\h5py_1482647201869\work\h5py\_objects.c:2866)()

h5py\_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (C:\Minonda\conda-bld\h5py_1482647201869\work\h5py\_objects.c:2824)()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\base.py in id(self)
    234     def id(self):
    235         """ Low-level identifier appropriate for this object """
--> 236         return self._id
    237 
    238     @property

AttributeError: 'MyH5' object has no attribute '_id'
```

My intention is to create an object with the attributes/methods of the h5py File class, but also add my own in this child class, but maybe the **init** of the parent isn't running?

I'm an engineer by day, and very new to defining classes, so be gentle...

Comment: If all you are changing is the initialization API, I think it would be simpler to write a function that takes care of receiving or asking for the name, then calls the `File`, and returns the resulting object.  In other words, a 'factory function' rather than a subclass.

Comment: @hpaulj so if I understand you correctly, I think I have already done that (not shown in the OP).  I created a module of functions to navigate/manipulate/plot data from a company-standard HDF structure.  My current approach allows easy creation of the h5py object and then to pull various time and data arrays into pandas Series' for analysis.  But I think it might be better to have these functions be methods of the h5py object itself... could be wrong too... just feeling out the options